# Dropdown form navigation on the same page as another form

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm looking to create a dropdown menu on our website that will appear on all pages in our navigation and is used to navigate to a set of particular brand pages. This is what I'm using:

```
<form>
<select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value" style="font-weight: normal; width: 170px;">
  <option value="">Select a brand...</option>
  <option value="brand-a.html">A</option>
  <option value="brand-b.html">B</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

It works great, however there is a conflict between it and the other form(s) that may show up on the same page of our site (ie., shopping cart page, billing/shipping info). For example, you fill in your billing info, click submit, and an error comes up from our shopping cart - I'm guessing because the brand form above doesn't have an option selected, and it's trying to submit that first.

Is there any way to have both forms on the page?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional details to help resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this need to be in a form? It shouldn't be inside the shopping cart (etc) form, at least. However, it sounds like your form processing is poorly written. It shouldn't be impacted by an additional element.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the form encapsulating the select tag. In HTML5 this is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `frame` to show more than one form in the same page. In the below code, I have shown 3 forms.

```
<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#FBE134" framespacing="0" rows="125,*" frameborder = "0" framespacing = "0" border = "0">
        <frame frameborder="0" noresize scrolling="no" name="framTop" src="header.php" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frameset frameborder="0" cols="170,*">
            <frame frameborder="0" name="framLeft" noresize scrolling="no" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
                <frame frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" noresize name="framRight" src="">
```